# BeautifulSoup 4: Dealing with urls containing <br />

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm dealing with html/xhtml links with beautifulsoup 4.3.2 and have faced some strangeness with br occuring in a elements.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = BeautifulSoup('<html><head></head><body><a href="/track?no=ABCD0000000">ABCD0000000<br /></a></body></html>')
html.find_all('a', text=re.compile('ABCD0000000', re.IGNORECASE))
```

Gives an empty list.

As I've found, it's caused by the br tag, appearing in the a tag.
Hmm. Well, lets replace it with a newline as someone advised here..

```
html.find('br').replaceWith('\n')
html.find_all('a', text=re.compile('ABCD0000000', re.IGNORECASE))
```

Again an empy list, damn.

Maybe,

```
html.find('br').replaceWith('')
html.find_all('a', text=re.compile('ABCD0000000', re.IGNORECASE))
```

The same result..

But

```
html = BeautifulSoup('<html><head></head><body><a href="/track?no=ABCD0000000">ABCD0000000</a></body></html>')
html.find_all('a', text=re.compile('ABCD0000000', re.IGNORECASE))

[<a href="/track?no=ABCD0000000">ABCD0000000</a>]
```

- Works fine.

So, as I see there is no way to bypass this except to clean or replace br's before feeding the data to bs4.

```
import re
re.sub(re.compile('<br\s*/>', re.IGNORECASE), '\n', '<html><head></head><body><a href="/track?no=ABCD0000000">ABCD0000000<br /></a></body></html>')
```

Or any?

Thanks for suggestions and complements.

Best regards,
 ~S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to remove all `br` tags using [`extract()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) and then perform the search:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = BeautifulSoup('<html><head></head><body><a href="/track?no=ABCD0000000">ABCD0000000<br /></a></body></html>')

for br in html('br'):
    br.extract()

print html.find_all('a', text=re.compile('ABCD0000000', re.IGNORECASE))
```

Prints:

```
[<a href="/track?no=ABCD0000000">ABCD0000000</a>]
```

---

Another option would be to check that `href` attribute ends with `ABCD0000000` using  [`CSS Selector`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
html.select('a[href$="ABCD0000000"]')
```

---

Another option would be to use [a function](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) and check that the link text starts with `ABCD0000000`:

```
html.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'a' and tag.text.startswith('ABCD0000000'))
```

Comment: Thanks for additions, but my description of the task was rather simplified. I still guess that removing br will be faster.

Comment: @Severogor ok, then having a real example could probably help me to give you more options.